# Can my program edit another program's registry entries in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, registry

If the entry is in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, can I just have my program add a key and value to any key in there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; any program can write to any key in HKCU.
There are no per-application permissions.

However, unelss you have a good reason to, you should avoid doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the registry is wide open to modification if you are running with administrative privileges on the machine.

Comment: You don't need admin privileges to write to HKCU.